# Multi-WAN CentOS router - Xfinity connection is Xfinicky. All other WAN connections work fine

Tags: centos, router

This problem has been driving me crazy for days.  I'm working on a prototype for a mini router/VPN client device to deploy to our employee's homes.  Currently due to family circumstances I'm actually working remotely from a different state and figured this is a good time to do this.

This router will have at least one connection to the end user's (in this case *my*) internet hardline as well as a connection via 4G/5G cellular for backup.

**The Problem**: I have 3 WAN interfaces (see below).  Two of them work flawlessly.  The Xfinity router connection will sometimes just not accept **any** traffic from my device.  I can always ping the Xfinity router itself.  Sometimes restarting the interface (e.g. `ifdown ethwan0 && ifup ethwan1`) will get it working -- other times not.  Once it starts working (i.e. transiting traffic to the public internet) it will work fine for an indefinite amount of time.

I can fail back and forth (using a custom script - below) between the other two WAN connections.  Once I fail over to the Xfinity connection mostly no traffic gets through.  (Neither via my router's SNAT nor a direct connection from my router.)

In the admin interface for the Xfinity router it lists my router's IP/MAC under "Offline Devices".  This is when I can in fact ping the Xfinity's IP from my router's interface.  I'm not sure what "offline" means in this case.

**Edit:**  I'm not 100% convinced, but in case the issue lies within the Xfinity device:

```
Technicolor TC8305C
Boot Version: 2.1.8_Technicolor
Core Version: 01.E6.01.22.59
HW Version: 1.5
```

I have one of those whitelabel fanless mini computers with 4 eth ports and 1 wifi card.  It's running CentOS 7 [ please spare me the lecture :) ]  Ports are as follows (as renamed in udev/rules.d):

`ethwan0` - Xfinity cable modem/router (the Xfinity device is **not** in bridge mode - NAT'd)

`ethwan1` - T-Mobile gateway device (also NAT'd)

`ethint`  - Internal connection for user's network with access to systems on other side of VPN

`ethgst`  - Guest connection for user's family or whatever.  Only access to internet.

`ethwifi` - Verizon hot spot (overkill but I'm testing).

Note that I have NetworkManager and firewalld **disabled** and I'm using `iptables-services` (I have a bunch of other centralized routers using iptables scripts so this is for consistency).  `selinux` is disabled.

**`ifcfg-ethwan0`**:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
DEFROUTE=no
NAME=ethwan1
DEVICE=ethwan1
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.242.12
PREFIX=24
```

**`ifcfg-ethwan1`**:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
DEFROUTE=no
NAME=ethwan0
DEVICE=ethwan0
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.38.1
PREFIX=24
```

**`ifcfg-ethwifi`**:

```
MODE=Managed
KEY_MGMT=WPA-PSK
TYPE=Wireless
BOOTPROTO=static
DEFROUTE=no
NAME=ethwifi
DEVICE=ethwifi
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.97.245
PREFIX=24
```

*Note:* I'm leaving out the wpa_supplicant config (& etc.) because this connection works OK and is not the issue.

**`iptables` config**:

```
*nat
-A POSTROUTING -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.38.168.0/24 -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.38.168.0/24 -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.38.168.0/24 -m state --state NEW -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.242.12
COMMIT
*filter
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.38.100.0/22 -d 10.38.168.0/24 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -m state --state NEW -s 10.38.168.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 10.38.168.0/24 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

**`failover-conn.bsh`** ***`[interface]`***:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Arg $1 is the interface name to fail over to (e.g. ethwan0)

declare -A snat_src
declare -A gateway
declare -A cidr

snat_src[ethwan0]="192.168.242.12"
gateway[ethwan0]="192.168.242.1"

snat_src[ethwan1]="192.168.38.1"
gateway[ethwan1]="192.168.38.11"

snat_src[ethwifi]="192.168.97.245"
gateway[ethwifi]="192.168.97.1"

# Should use awk here but this does work.

snat_line_num=`iptables -t nat -nL --line-numbers |grep SNAT |grep "10\.38\.168\.0\/24" |grep -oP "^[0-9]+"`

# This looks foolish but it's in case a malfunction caused more than one rule to be put in place.. it's happened to me before and this overkill can't hurt.

for whatever in 1 2 3; do

        ip route del default

        iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s 10.38.168.0/24 -m state --state NEW -j SNAT --to-source ${snat_src[ethwan0]}
        iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s 10.38.168.0/24 -m state --state NEW -j SNAT --to-source ${snat_src[ethwan1]}
        iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s 10.38.168.0/24 -m state --state NEW -j SNAT --to-source ${snat_src[ethwifi]}

done

ip route add default via ${gateway[$1]} dev $1

iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING ${snat_line_num} -s 10.38.168.0/24 -m state --state NEW -j SNAT --to-source ${snat_src[$1]}

conntrack -D

# I thought flushing the ARP cache might cause a re-announce to the Xfinity modem and make it play nice.  I tested with/without this and same result.

ip -s -s neigh flush all

# Without the sleep the VPNs timeout a couple of times before connecting anyway.

sleep 10

systemctl restart openvpn@client-REDACTED0
systemctl restart openvpn@client-REDACTED1
```

**Here are a series of commands/results that illustrate the problem:**

```
./failover-conn.bsh ethwan0

# ping from router or SNAT'd connection to 8.8.8.8 may return one pong then unlimited timeouts, no responses at all, or it will be fully functional.  VPNs may or may not connect after some time; EVEN IF PINGS ARE FAILING CONSTANTLY..???

ifdown ethwan0 && ifup ethwan0

# pings may or may not get responses or timeout depending on the phase of the moon...?

./failover-conn.bsh ethwan1

# Everything works flawlessly.  Can ping from router, from SNAT'd clients, and VPNs connect.  All traffic transits correctly.

./failover-conn.bsh ethwifi

# Everything works flawlessly.  Can ping from router, from SNAT'd clients, and VPNs connect.  All traffic transits correctly.

./failover-conn.bsh ethwan0

# Same as the first time.  May or may not work.
```

Here's what I tried on the Xfinity router:

- Completely turned off firewall / IDS (I thought maybe the IDS would be annoyed by the double NAT).
- Added my router as a "reserved device"
- Verified that all blocking/parental features were off.
- Connected another laptop directly to the Xfinity device's wifi and left a ping open to ensure that the actual device/internet connection was up while I was testing my router.  It was up.
- Set my router's IP as the DMZ host (long shot but ????? profit)
- Connecting a spare laptop via hardline to the Xfinity gateway and testing/pinging.  That laptop always worked fine when my router was failing.
- **Restarting/rebooting the Xfinity router *does* restore connectivity**.  (Rebooting my router does not.)

On my router I tried:

- Disabling VPNs
- Disabling iptables
- Disabling all other interfaces
- Changing `ifcfg-ethwan0` to have `DEFROUTE=yes` and `GATEWAY=192.168.242.1` so that this was just like any "normal" computer
- Swapping `ethwan0` and `ethwan1` both physically and in config.  Regardless of the port it was connected to, the Xfinity device was unreliable and the T-Mobile gateway worked just fine.
- Swapping ethernet cables all over the place.

**I am so perplexed by this.** Every other device I connect to this freakin' Xfinity device works great.  It just has a problem with this mini computer.  But as I said, the mini computer works great with the T-Mo router, as well as with all the clients on `ethint`.

I'm out of troubleshooting steps and I'm hoping that one of you had a similar problem and found a solution.

Or maybe you'll spot a glaringly obvious face-palm error in my configs or methodology?  I hope it's that.  At least then I'll know it wasn't GiTM.

Thanks in advance!
-Scott